# How to access a component property from App.vue

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, vuejs2

I used vue-loader to help me install vue and webpack
I have a file called App.vue

In App.vue I added a component called widget. If I clicked some button there's a function that set the `btnClicked = true` hence the widget appears

```
<widget v-show="btnClicked"></widget>
```

but I also want that function to access the `widgetShowMe`, it's a property in my component.

I want the function activated in my `App.vue` to also set **`widgetShowMe = true`**
I tried this but it didn't work

```
methods:{
  btnClickedFunc () {
    this.btnClicked = true;
    Widget.widgetShowMe = true; 
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because firstly to access methods on your component you need to `Component.methods.methodName` post which, you still won't be able to use it like this and you shouldn't. Could you please specify what is it that you want to achieve with the inner components function?

Comment: i'm not trying to access a method, i need to access a component data so i also tried Widget.data.widgetShowMe = true; and it didn't work
all i want is to show a component once a button is clicked

Comment: Okay, It wouldn't work that way. You would be better off using v-model. I'll add an answer to show how.

Comment: Can you add the code for the Widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Accessing child component's data in parent component in vuejs

If you have a parent component called `parent` and child component called child, you can communicate between each other using `props` and `events`.

1. `props`: Facilitates communication from parent to child.
2. `events`: Can be used to pass data in a child component to the parent component.

For this question we require events and will use `v-model` to make the child component usable everywhere with much less setup.

```js
Vue.component('counter', {
  template: `<div><button @click='add'>+1</button>
  <button @click='sub'>-1</button>
  <div>this is inside the child component: {{ result }}</div></div>`,
  data () {
    return {
      result: 0
    }
  },
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    emitResult () {
      this.$emit('input', this.result)
    },
    add () {
      this.result += 1
      this.emitResult()
    },
    sub () {
      this.result -= 1
      this.emitResult()
    }
  }  
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data () {
    return {
      resultFromChild: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='demo'>
  <counter v-model='resultFromChild'></counter>
  This is in parent component {{ resultFromChild }}
</div>
```

### Custom component with v-model

This needs two [requirements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events).

1. You have a prop on the child component with the name `value`.

   ```
    props: ['value'], // this part in the child component snippet
   ```
2. You emit the event `input` with the value.

   ```
    this.$emit('input', this.result) // this part in the child component snippet
   ```

All you need to think of is, when to emit the event with the value of `widgetShowMe`, and your `app.vue` can easily capture the value inside your `widget`.